# Connecting Keyboard actions to UIButton Actions in Mac Catalyst App

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ipad, mac-catalyst

I have a Mac Catalyst App that for the sake of this question, you can assume it's a calculator. Therefore, it has a lot of UIButtons. Everything works fine. But what I really want to be able to is to connect the physical keyboards actions, for example pressing 1, 2, 3, ... buttons on the keyboard to the corresponding UIButtons for those keys. How can I do that? Again, it's a Mac Catalyst App not a macOS app.

Comment: I don't think Catalyst supports keyboard inputs like that yet, I believe that is a feature they plan to add though

Comment: I don't know how you got your insider information but you were right about that and Apple did add the support as the accepted answer suggests and shows the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With iOS 13.4, you can use UIResponder's `pressesBegan:` to catch UIKey based UIEvents

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/handling_key_presses_made_on_a_physical_keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to work if:

0) Create a structure for simple building of the UIKeyCommands

```
struct keyCommand {
    var input: String;
    var modifiers: UIKeyModifierFlags
}
```

`
1) subclass UIWIndow
2) You override the keyCommands variable in the "scene window" and create key commands for each key you want the window to capture.   My app has multiple scenes, so an scene ID string I save is used to show which is currenty  in focus (the first responder)

```
class Window: UIWindow{
    var model: CCModel! // will load after the window established
    var app: AppDelegate!
    var scene: String!
    var keyCommandList: [keyCommand]
    var commands: [UIKeyCommand]?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        keyCommandList = [

            //arrow keys
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifiers:[]),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifiers:.alternate),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifiers:.command),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifiers: .shift),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow, modifiers:[]),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow, modifiers:.alternate),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow, modifiers:.command),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow, modifiers: .shift),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow, modifiers:[]),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow, modifiers:.alternate),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow, modifiers:.command),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow, modifiers: .shift),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow, modifiers:[]),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow, modifiers:.alternate),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow, modifiers:.command),
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow, modifiers: .shift),

            //escape
            keyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputEscape, modifiers: []),

            // a (play arpegio), A - progression arpegio
            keyCommand(input: "a", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "a", modifiers: .shift),

            // c (play chord), S - progression chord
            keyCommand(input: "c", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "c", modifiers: .shift),

            // tab key,
            keyCommand(input: "\t", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "\t", modifiers: .shift),

            // return
            keyCommand(input: "\r", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "\r", modifiers: .shift),

            // +
            keyCommand(input: "+", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "=", modifiers: []),

            // -
            keyCommand(input: "-", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "_", modifiers: []),

            // space

            keyCommand(input: " ", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "0", modifiers: []), // toggle the accents

            keyCommand(input: "p", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "s", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "s", modifiers: .alternate),
            keyCommand(input: "s", modifiers: .command),


            keyCommand(input: "i", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "k", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "?", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "t", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "r", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "o", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "d", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "w", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "h", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "l", modifiers: []),



            keyCommand(input: "1", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "2", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "3", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "4", modifiers: []),
            keyCommand(input: "5", modifiers: []),

        ]
        self.commands = []
        for command in self.keyCommandList {
            let keycommand = UIKeyCommand(input: command.input, modifierFlags: command.modifiers, action: #selector(self.captureKey(sender:)))

            self.commands!.append(keycommand)
        }
        super.init(frame: frame)

   open override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        return self.commands
    }

    @objc func captureKey(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
        self.model.onKeyCapture(sender, scene: self.scene)
    }
}
```

3) Send the captured key and modifiers to a delegate to manage it.  In my case this is the methods self.model.method. (model is a singleton class for this app).

```
func onKeyCapture(_ sender: UIKeyCommand, scene: String) {
        let app = getApp()
        let input = sender.input
        let modifiers = sender.modifierFlags
        if scene == "main" {
            // handle main screen key commands
            // mode independent commands
            switch input {
            case "k","1":
                setMode(value: "C")
                selectSegment(0)
                return
            case "s","2":
                if modifiers == [] {  // allow modified "s" through
                    setMode(value: "S")
                    selectSegment(1)
                    return
                }
            case "i","?","3":
                setMode(value: "I")
                selectSegment(2)
                return
            case "p","4":
                setMode(value: "P")
                selectSegment(3)
                return
            default:
                break
            }
            switch input {
            case "t":
                switch modifiers {
                   case []:
                        playTuning()
                        return
                   default:
                       break
                   }
            default:
                break
            }
            switch mode {
            case "C": // chord mode
                switch input {
                case UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow:
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        nextPrev(type: .prev)
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow:
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        nextPrev(type: .next)
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow:
                     switch modifiers {
                     case []:
                        app.chordTVC!.setbyKeyCommand(delta: +1)
                     default:
                         break
                     }
                 case UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow:
                     switch modifiers {
                     case []:
                         app.chordTVC!.setbyKeyCommand(delta: -1)
                     default:
                         break
                     }
                case " ":
                    toggleShowChordScale()
                case "0":
                    app.fretboardVC!.toggleAccents()
                case "c":
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        playChord()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case "a":
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        playArpeggio()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case "+","=":
                    if root == nil { // no root chosen, so set it to "C"
                        app.rootTVC!.setRootByValue(key: "C")
                    } else { // raise the key a semitone
                        incrementDecrementKey(direction: 1)
                    }
                case "-","_":
                    if root == nil { // no root chosen, so set it to "C"
                        app.rootTVC!.setRootByValue(key: "C")
                    } else { // lower the key a semitone
                        incrementDecrementKey(direction: -1)
                    }
                case "r":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NOROOT_OK")
                case "5":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO5TH_OK")
                case "o":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO_OPEN")
                case "d":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO_DEAD")
                case "w":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO_WIDOW")
                case "h":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleHighLow("high")
                case "l":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleHighLow("low")
                default:
                    break
                }
            case "S": // Scale mode
                switch input {
                case UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow:
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                       app.scaleTVC!.setbyKeyCommand(delta: +1)
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow:
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        app.scaleTVC!.setbyKeyCommand(delta: -1)
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case "+","=":
                    if root == nil { // no root chosen, so set it to "C"
                        app.rootTVC!.setRootByValue(key: "C")
                    } else { // raise the key a semitone
                        incrementDecrementKey(direction: 1)
                    }
                case "-","_":
                    if root == nil { // no root chosen, so set it to "C"
                        app.rootTVC!.setRootByValue(key: "C")
                    } else { // lower the key a semitone
                        incrementDecrementKey(direction: -1)
                    }
               case " ":
                   switch modifiers {
                   case []: // two finger tap equivalent
                        if scaleDisplayMode == "notes" {
                           scaleDisplayMode = "tones"
                       } else {
                           scaleDisplayMode = "notes"
                       }
                       FretboardNeedsDisplay()
                   default:
                       break
                   }
                case "a":
                    showAccents = !showAccents
                    FretboardNeedsDisplay()
                case "\r":
                    if modifiers == []{
                        playScale()
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            case "I": // Identify mode
                switch input {
                default:
                    break
                }
            case "P": // Progression mode
                switch input {
                case UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow:
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        nextPrev(type: .prev)
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow:
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        nextPrev(type: .next)
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow:  // next previous progression
                     switch modifiers {
                     case []:
                        app.progDisplayTVC!.setbyKeyCommand(delta: +1)
                     default:
                         break
                     }
                 case UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow:
                     switch modifiers {
                     case []:
                         app.progDisplayTVC!.setbyKeyCommand(delta: -1)
                     default:
                         break
                     }
                case " ":
                    toggleShowChordScale()
                case "0":
                    app.fretboardVC!.toggleAccents()
                case "c":
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        playChord()
                    case .shift:
                        progPlayChord()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case "a":
                    switch modifiers {
                    case []:
                        playArpeggio()
                    case .shift:
                        progPlayArp()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                case "+","=":
                    if root == nil { // no root chosen, so set it to "C"
                        app.rootTVC!.setRootByValue(key: "C")
                    } else { // raise the key a semitone
                        incrementDecrementKey(direction: 1)
                    }
                case "-","_":
                    if root == nil { // no root chosen, so set it to "C"
                        app.rootTVC!.setRootByValue(key: "C")
                    } else { // lower the key a semitone
                        incrementDecrementKey(direction: -1)
                    }
                case "r":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NOROOT_OK")
                case "5":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO5TH_OK")
                case "o":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO_OPEN")
                case "d":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO_DEAD")
                case "w":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleFilter("NO_WIDOW")
                case "h":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleHighLow("high")
                case "l":
                    app.filtersCVC!.toggleHighLow("low")
                default:
                    break
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        else if scene == "help" {
            // handle help screen key commands

        }

    }
```